# Spring boot with ssl enabled and Elastic Beanstalk - Files not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up a spring boot app with ssl enabled = true. On my local machine everything works fine and as expected. My truststore and keystore are separate files. Both are located under src/main/resources/static/ssl/. So far so good. But if I deploy my application on elastic beanstalk i get the following log:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/app/current/src/main/resources/static/ssl/keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)

Why does my app not recognize this path in elastic beanstalk?I set the paths in the application.properties file. Do I have to set the path additionally anywhere?

The Problem isn't here that ssl doesn't work, but the files aren't found.

Comment: Configure that inside the hidden folder `.ebextensions` .. all the best of luck !

Comment: Put them in a folder other than `src`. Your source code won't be in the instance while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the solution is actually quite easy. In the application properties file you have only to set classpath before it. So i moved the files in the src/main/resources folder and set them in the properties file this way:

```
server.ssl.key-store =classpath:keystore.jks
```

That's it.